# python clearing unittest.mock full history

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I'm using `unittest.mock` and it seems like it leaks a lot of objects.

I'm making sure to always use `with` statements, e.g. `with mock.patch.object(target=...):`

Yet I can see a lot of objects of type `unittest.mock._CallList`, `unittest.mock._CallList`, `unittest.mock.MagicProxy` and others.

Is there a way to clear that after each test executed or something similar?

Comment: can you provide a simple code example to illustrate the problem?

Answer (score -1):

I didnt got your question fully.

So, after mocking a object you found that there is a lot of calls to it? And then want to reset ?

You can use `reset_mock`

Here is a example:

Create `script.py`

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client("ssm")
client2 = boto3.client("sqm")
```

Create `test_a.py`

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

@patch("boto3.client")
def test_boto(boto3):
    import script
    assert len(boto3.mock_calls) == 2
    boto3.reset_mock()
    assert len(boto3.mock_calls) == 0
```

Run with `python3 -m pytest`